# Is it possible to change domain account password remotely on a domain-joined server which is not DC?

Tags: passwords, windows-server, windowsdomainaccount

I have a domain with 2 windows servers, one is DC (domain controller).

I want to change a domain account password automatically, with WinRM remote command `NET USER my_account new_pwd /domain` on the non-DC (not the domain controller) server.

I've tried to:

- Login to the DC with WinRM, and remotely execute the command. It works.
- Login to the non-DC server with WinRM, and remotely execute the command. Got "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied".

  By the way, a similiar command without `/domain` argument `NET USER my_local_account new_pwd`, runs successfully and changes my local account password.
- Login to the non-DC server directly with RDP, and locally execute the command. Works.

  I think it proves that changing domain password from the non-DC server is allowed, but changing remotely is restricted.

Is it possible to avoid the "system error 5" and change domain password remotelly on a non-DC server?